# How to fix the animation in the google-map-marker with Polymer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers, polymer-3.x

I try to add animation in google-map-marker within Polymer 3.0 but it cannot work with animation.

I find out the attributes from google-map-marker in webcomponents for adding animation(BOUNCE), then I test it to none animation.

```
      <google-map latitude="" longitude="" api-key="[[apiKey]]" zoom="13" language="en" fit-to-markers>
          <google-map-marker animation="BOUNCE" slot="markers" id="marker" latitude="" longitude="" api-key="[[apiKey]]"></google-map-marker>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[locations]]">
            <google-map-marker slot="markers" latitude="[[item.lat]]" longitude="[[item.lon]]" api-key="[[apiKey]]"></google-map-marker>
          </template>
      </google-map>
```

It is none error when I test animation in google-map-marker.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like this issue has been reported here too https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/441

Comment: Yes. I think there had bugs. Some days, I find the medicine code for the google-map-marker bug but I cannot find out.